# How can I pick from this string?

Tags: python, string, list, typeerror, python-2.5

Query

```sql
SELECT leaveZoneVelocity, leaveZoneVelocityZ, leaveZoneVelocityXYZ
FROM stageentertimes WHERE player_id=? AND map_id=? ORDER BY duration ASC
```

Code:

```
leavestart_t1_all = [{u'leaveZoneVelocityZ': 0L, u'leaveZoneVelocityXYZ': 245L, u'leaveZoneVelocity': 245L}]

leavestart_t1 = leavestart_t1_all["leaveZoneVelocity"]

leavestart_t1 = leavestart_t1_all[3]
```

I get for the first `leave_start_t1`

```
TypeError: list indices must be integer
```

and for the 2nd one:

```
List index out of range
```

Hope you can kinda help me, and maybe giving me an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list with *one* dictionary. Index the list, then the dictionary returned:

```
leavestart_t1 = leavestart_t1_all[0]["leaveZoneVelocity"]
```

Here `leavestart_t1_all[0]` indexes the outer list, returning the dictionary contained.

If you are using a SQL library, instead of using `cursor.fetch_all()` you can use `cursor.fetch_one()` to just get that first row, and no indexing is then required.

Comment: Oh well, i just mixed it abit.. My bad and I was using the fetch_all there. Thank you for your response